# How do you set pool size in production using rails and rubber gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, postgresql-9.1, rubber

I am using rails 3.2 and postgres 9.1. I'm hosting on Amazon EC2 instance, and using capistrano and rubber to deploy.

So my question is, since I don't set database options in database.yml for production, how do I increase the pool size from the default 5?

My guess is in config/rubber/rubber-postgresql.yml, but I don't know what to actually put in there to change the pool size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database.yml is generated by rubber. There is a config file to play with. config/rubber/common/database.yml

in there you can play with your database settings.  Specifically, you will see that the pool size has a default value that you can change.